# React-router authentication example

Tags: reactjs, session, react-router, session-cookies

I am trying to just understand how the example works in the docs [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow). I understand that the `fakeAuth` object is mimicking some type of login module. What I don't understand is that how is this secure with the `isAuthenticated` field? Couldn't someone just change this field to `true` and then be allowed to enter those protected routes?

I read somewhere that I should just ensure that all my API endpoints are secure themselves, which makes sense, so even if they were to access the protected routes they would still see no information, but is there a way to ensure that these pages never get visited?

Second question, how could I adapt that example to use my session cookies that my server gave me? Would I just have to try to login on every route change using like a HOC as in the example?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I can partially answer your question.

> I am trying to just understand how the example works in the docs here.
>   I understand that the fakeAuth object is mimicking some type of login
>   module. What I don't understand is that how is this secure with the
>   isAuthenticated field? Couldn't someone just change this field to true
>   and then be allowed to enter those protected routes?

=> Yes, one could change this field to true and be allowed to enter those protected routes.

> I read somewhere that I should just ensure that all my API endpoints
>   are secure themselves, which makes sense, so even if they were to
>   access the protected routes they would still see no information

=> Yes, you are right.

> but is there a way to ensure that these pages never get visited?

=> You will have to use a tightly coupled architecture, for example using Spring Boot + Thymeleaf( ref : https://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/ ) to achieve this where entire pages are returned instead of some data. However, it might be difficult to scale this application to other devices ( like mobile, tablet ) if required.